# Synchronise one process and parallel group

Tags: java, android

I'm getting ConcurrentModificationException, so i decided to try something new.

I have an ArrayList of points, which is used in Recycler View for download all graphs in parallel threads.

Is it possible to lock this downloads, when i'm writing to ArrayList and not having a chain download later?

Because now i'm using this in my Fragment:

```
public static final Object lock = new Object();
synchronized (lock) { /*download and write to ArrayList*/ }
```

And in every Cell i want to use

```
synchronized (lock) { /*download graphs*/ }
```

And i think when one cell is loading graph, all will wait, then second will load and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentModificationException` usually indicates that a collection was modified while an iterator was in progress. It's not necessarily in a different  thread :

```
List<Object> someList = new ArrayList<>();
someList.add("an item");

for (Object item : someList) {
    // throws ConcurrentModificationException
    someList.add("a new item");
}
```

It's difficult to know what really happen in your case. What happen if you replace `ArrayList`s with [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) ? They are much less efficient than `ArrayList`s but it probably doesn't matter, at least compared to network operations.

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm using Collections.sort() as well, which is not supported by CopyOnWriteArrayList. But anyway, will upvote answer, because i haven't heard before about CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: Can you replace it with `theList.sort(null)` ? In fact it is exactly what `Collections.sort(theList)` does (but only if targetSdk > 25)

Comment: Probably it will not work, because i'm using 4 different types of sort with comparators. Alright, since there is no other answers, i mark that, because in most cases it's still valid. Thanks